# Will this SensorHub work?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, power, adafruit

As a project I have to build a SensorHub with multiple sensors. I am relatively new to the Arduino and circuit world, so I need a little help.

The Goal is to build hub with multiple sensors and to be able to measure power consumption of the entire thing and log the data from all sensors.

So I came up with the following part list:

- Arduino Uno (Rev3)
- Adafruit 10-DOF IMU L3GD20H + LSM303 + BMP180
- Adafruit Ultimate GPS v3
- Adafruit VCNL4010 Proximity and Light sensor
- Adafruit INA219 High Side DC Current Sensor Breakout
- Adafruit MicroSD card breakout board
- of course breadboard, powersupply, calbes, etc.

Everything is connected like this:

[image: SensorHub diagram]

My question is now if this thing will work as I expect. With the 10-DOF, GPS and VCNL4010 I'm pretty sure. They work all with I2C on different addresses and all of them need 5V.

The question is now if I can measure the needed power with this setup. Or does the INA219 need power to be able to get the power to the Arduino? Do you see any problems?

Comment: By “measure the needed power”, do you mean like with a DVM?  That is, by manually taking meter readings of currents and voltages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The INA219 breakout will pass current, even if it doesn't receive any power itself.

Comment: So, do you think this will work?

Comment: The current sensing part; yes. I haven't really looked at the rest of the circuit.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Let's see what others say to the remaining parts :)

Comment: Well, in the schematic both the red and black wire are connected to the GND pin on the INA219.

Comment: I was a bit worried about the I2C pull-up resistors on the boards, as  the INA pulls up to 5 volt and the other two boards run on 3.3V. But the VCNL doesn't mind 5v on it's I2C pins, even though it runs on 3.3V. And the 10-DOF uses a buffer between the chips and the I2C pins on the breakout. So that's fine too.

Comment: Marked this answer as solution since the solution is in the comments. Thank you :)